# button toggle event onkeyup from body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with this function. Clicking a button, the onkeyup event present in the body tag must be deactivated, and then pressing it again must reactivate

```html
<body onkeyup="NoPreview()">
...
</body>
```

```
function NoPreview() {
var preview = true;
if (preview == true) {
document.body.onkeyup = null;
preview = false;
} else {
return true; }
}
```

the function was deactivated, but clicking again on the button, does not reactivate.

Comment: Hi @Sim9b can you paste you're html code

Comment: This is happen because you preview value is always true when you call the function. Take out ´var preview = true´ from your function

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a global variable and store the status of your setting, like this

```
<body onkeyup="NoPreview()">
<button onClick="toggleKeyup()">Toggle</button>
</body>
```

and the js:

```
var enableKeyup = true;
function toggleKeyup() {
  enableKeyup = !enableKeyup;
}
function NoPreview() {
  if(enableKeyup) {
  // Your code here...
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("."));
  }
}
```

this way you don't have to add and remove events and you can have more settings for your NoPreview function.

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/wyzix33/pen/bXBPbz

Hope it helps :)

Happy codding!